# Run cat command in Android

Tags: android, command-line, terminal, exec

I want to concatenate two files in android. I did this from the Terminal Emulator app using the command `cat file1 file2 > output_file`. But it does not work when I try to execute it from my code.

This is the code that I used to execute the command.

```
    public String exec() {
    try {

        // Executes the command.
        String CAT_COMMAND = "/system/bin/cat /sdcard/file1 /sdcard/file2 > /sdcard/output_file";
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CAT_COMMAND);

        // Reads stdout.
        // NOTE: You can write to stdin of the command using
        //       process.getOutputStream().
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        int read;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.append(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        reader.close();

        // Waits for the command to finish.
        process.waitFor();

        return output.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I have given the permission to write to external storage in the manifest. What am I missing?

Comment: To run a process, you need a shell right?!?

Comment: Actually you do not need a shell to run an external process. However you do need a shell to do a process output redirect (`>`).

Comment: Oh! what other way is there to do a concatenation then?

Comment: Just do it via simple java code - see my answer.

Comment: I dont understand. Isn't Terminal Emulator just another normal app?

Comment: Yes, "Terminal Emulator" is an app on the Android Market. It has nothing to do with your solution.

Comment: No I was wondering how they have done it in that app. Never mind. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comment, you need a shell to do process output redirect (via the `>`).

You can simply append files via this code:

```
void append(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst, true);  // `true` means append 

    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
       out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

In your case call it twice for `file1` and `file2`.

Comment: thanks. I was making it too complex :D

Also, is there some way to merge two video files?

Comment: Merging video files is an entirely different problem. First they need to be unpacked from container (.avi or .mp4), then video streams need to be decoded, then appended into one, then encoded and then packed into container. This is a job for a video encoding/decoding library (e.g. ffmpeg). Android does not come with such functionality.

Comment: Btw, if answer sufficiently answers your question, then you can accept it, right?

Comment: it didn't work for video files , it just played the first chunked of the video file

Comment: there is a little error, you are putting `true` in the `FileInputStream` constructor but it should go to the `FileOutputStream` where you actually want to append